# Cannot get same cursor for all objects and events in a window

Tags: python, gtk3

I have searched and tested a lot and have not found a way to force a window and all children use the same cursor for all events.

In the example code below I want the `DIAMOND_CROSS` cursor used even when hovering over the `Gtk.Paned` handle. As it is now it switches to the horizontal sizing arrow.

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gdk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gdk, Gtk

class MainWindow(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.connect("realize", self.on_realize)
        self.connect('delete_event', Gtk.main_quit)
        self.set_default_size(800, 600)

        button1 = Gtk.Button('Button 1')
        button2 = Gtk.Button('Button 2')

        paned = Gtk.Paned()
        paned.set_position(400)
        paned.add1(button1)
        paned.add2(button2)

        self.add(paned)
        self.show_all()

    def on_realize(self, widget):
        cursor = Gdk.Cursor(Gdk.CursorType.DIAMOND_CROSS)
        self.get_window().set_cursor(cursor)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win = MainWindow()
    Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked the source of the `paned` object which has the following code in the `gtk_paned_state_flags_changed` function:

```
if (gtk_widget_is_sensitive (widget))
    cursor = gdk_cursor_new_from_name (gtk_widget_get_display (widget),
                                       priv->orientation == GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL
                                       ? "col-resize" : "row-resize");
else
    cursor = NULL;
```

(https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/gtkpaned.c?h=3.18.6#n1866)

Thus in theory you could overwrite the `do_state_flags_changed` function of the `paned` widget (and all other widget that have behavior like this) to achieve the result you want.

But as you ask for a way to set the cursor for all objects in one go the answer is simply: No, that is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for this. Ineed it seems like one good start point to fix my issue. I'll dig into it. I do not have enough rep to vote up your answer btw, so you have to settle with this comment :)

Comment: Just for your information, even without rep it is possible to accept answers. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work